# Unity - "Como centralizar e atualizar todas as variáveis do Jogo?"

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

**Engine: Unity (5.4.3).**

**Linguagem de script utilizada: C#**

**Cenário:** 
O jogo está dividido em cenas, cada cena composta por inimigos e armadilhas, cada inimigo composto por suas armas, e cada um desses elementos composto por suas respectivas variáveis.

**Problema:**
Agora, na etapa de balanço de jogo, para não se tornar um trabalho artesanal, modificando os parâmetros de cada inimigo e armadilha separadamente (ou até mesmo através dos seus respectivos prefabs)... eu desejo fazer algo como: 
***"Centralizar todas as variáveis em um banco de dados que eu possa facilmente atualizar em lotes"***

**Considerações:**

- Precisa ser em formato de tabelas (csv,fdb,xlsx,sql);
- Precisa ser "offline", como uma mini-database embedded;
- Podem ser "assets" da *Unity Asset Store* que tiveram experiências de
  uso satisfatórias;

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver usando C#, aqui vai uma ideia:
Crie uma classe no padrão Singleton e utilize propriedades nessa classe. Desta forma você pode utilizá-las em qualquer ponto do game. (Pode ser uma classe estática também, mas eu usaria um Singleton mesmo).
Você pode fazer com que o "set" das propriedades já atualizem o valor no banco e o "get" já retornem do banco também, o que agilizaria bastante, porém não sei se isso pode ser bom no seu caso por questões de performance, mas vale o teste.

Comment: Esse é um bom caminho. Entretanto, o acesso concorrente a um único objeto Singleton pode ser complicado se informações forem atualizadas durante o jogo (se só forem lidas, é ok). Outra alternativa é armazenar os dados em uma estrutura local e fazer cada objeto saber ler/atualizar seus próprios dados. Haverão compartilhamentos, mas serão apenas de instâncias em um mesmo nível hierárquico.

Comment: Quanto à implementação, se precisa ser em "formato de tabela" (tipo CSV - mas por que?), você vai ter que implementar Ivan. Mas a Unity tem soluções pra isso com o [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) e até mesmo com [serialização em XML](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer).